# Ange bisector - how to choose bisector of interior angle

Tags: geometry, triangles, angle

Let points A,B,C be the vertices of the triangle and vertex B be also a vertex of angle we want to divide.

Inspired by construction I derived following way to write equation for angle bisector :-

1. Write equation for the lines including rays of triangle
2. On the one of the rays choose point D
3. Write equation of circle with center at B and radius BD
4. Let point E be intersection of circle and other ray of the angle
   (ray on which don't lies point D)
5. Write equation for line through points D and E
6. Write equation for line perpendicular to DE and passing through the point B

   Steps 5. and 6. can be combined into one if we know equation for perpendicular line

Problem is in step 4. We write system of equations from which we get two points E 
but only one of them will give us equation of interior angle 
and how to choose correct one

Comment: Suppose the equation for the line $BA$ is $ax+by+c=0$. Then the desired point $E$ and the ray $BC$ must both lie in either $ax+by+c<0 $ or $ax+by+c>0$ at the same time. Using this, you can find the desired point $E$ by simply calculating the value of $ax+by+c$ at $E$.

Comment: Writing program in my favourite programming language i have to give concrete condition which can be stored in boolean variable to be able to exclude one of the points E I calculate value of ax+by+c at E for both points E and what i can do with this

Comment: Assume the ray BC lie in the region $ax+by+c<0.$ Then you choose E to be the point for which the value of $ax+by+c$ is less than zero. To check if the ray BC lie in the region $ax+by+c <0$, you take any point on ray BC and check if the value of $ax+by+c$ at this point is less than zero. Similar reasoning follows if the ray BC lie in $ax+by+c >0$.

Comment: $( ax_{E}+by_{E}+c )( ax_{C} + by_{C} +c) > 0$
Is this condition be ok ?

Comment: Yes! This would work.

Comment: I wrote some code in Pascal 
https://pastebin.com/SX2NAM2x
and i think that your suggestion does not work
Pascal code is very easy to read (even easier than C code)
If you comment main loop you can check yourself on online compilers that something is wrong and boolean variable is not set correctly

Answer (score 1):

Let's perform some calculations.
Warning: they are quite lengthy.

$$l_{AB}:y-y_{B}=\frac{y_{B}-y_{A}}{x_{B}-x_{A}}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
l_{AB}:\left(y-y_{B}\right)\left(x_{B}-x_{A}\right)=\left(y_{B}-y_{A}\right)\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
l_{AB}:\left(y_{B}-y_{A}\right)\left(x-x_{B}\right)-\left(y-y_{B}\right)\left(x_{B}-x_{A}\right)=0\\
l_{AB}:\left(y_{B}-y_{A}\right)x-\left(x_{B}-x_{A}\right)y-x_{B}\left(y_{B}-y_{A}\right)+y_{B}\left(x_{B}-x_{A}\right)=0
$$
$$
l_{BC}:y-y_{C}=\frac{y_{C}-y_{B}}{x_{C}-x_{B}}\left(x-x_{C}\right)\\
l_{BC}:\left(y-y_{C}\right)\left(x_{C}-x_{B}\right)=\left(y_{C}-y_{B}\right)\left(x-x_{C}\right)\\
l_{BC}:\left(y_{C}-y_{B}\right)\left(x-x_{C}\right)-\left(x_{C}-x_{B}\right)\left(y-y_{C}\right)=0\\
l_{BC}:\left(y_{C}-y_{B}\right)x-\left(x_{C}-x_{B}\right)y-x_{C}\left(y_{C}-y_{B}\right)+y_{B}\left(x_{C}-x_{B}\right)=0
$$
$$
l_{AC}:y-y_{C}=\frac{y_{C}-y_{A}}{x_{C}-x_{A}}\left(x-x_{C}\right)\\
l_{AC}:\left(x_{C}-x_{A}\right)\left(y-y_{C}\right)=\left(y_{C}-y_{A}\right)\left(x-x_{C}\right)\\
l_{AC}:\left(y_{C}-y_{A}\right)\left(x-x_{C}\right)-\left(x_{C}-x_{A}\right)\left(y-y_{C}\right)=0\\
l_{AC}:\left(y_{C}-y_{A}\right)x-\left(x_{C}-x_{A}\right)y-x_{C}\left(y_{C}-y_{A}\right)+y_{C}\left(x_{C}-x_{A}\right)=0
$$

Let general equation of $l_{AB}$ be 
$$A_{1}x+B_{1}y+C_{1}=0$$
Let general equation of $l_{BC}$ be 
$$A_{2}x+B_{2}y+C_{2}=0$$
Let general equation of $l_{AC}$ be 
$$A_{3}x+B_{3}y+C_{3}=0$$

Let's write bisector equations for vertices A and B.

Begin with vertex B. For simplicity, assume that our point D is equal to point A.

$$|BA|=\sqrt{\left(x_{A}-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(y_{A}-y_{B}\right)^2}\\
|BA|=\sqrt{A_{1}^2+B_{1}^2}\\
|BA|=c\\
|CB|=\sqrt{\left(x_{B}-x_{C}\right)^2+\left(y_{B}-y_{C}\right)^2}\\
|CB|=\sqrt{A_{2}^2+B_{2}^2}\\
|CB|=a
$$

From step 4. we have system of equations

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(y-y_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     A_{2}x+B_{2}y+C_{2}=0
   \end{align}
\right.
$$
$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(y-y_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)-y_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)+y_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x_{B}+C_{2}\right)\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A_{2}}{B_{2}}x-\frac{A_{2}}{B_{2}}x_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\left(\frac{A_{2}}{B_{2}}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2+\frac{A_{2}^2}{B_{2}^2}\left(x-x_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(1+\frac{A_{2}^2}{B_{2}^2}\right)\left(x-x_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \frac{B_{2}^2+A_{2}^2}{B_{2}^2}\left(x-x_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \frac{a^2}{B_{2}^2}\left(x-x_{B}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2=B_{2}^2\cdot\frac{c^2}{a^2} \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}\right)^2-B_{2}^2\cdot\frac{c^2}{a^2}=0\\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{B}-B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)\left(x-x_{B}+B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)=0\\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
     x=x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a} \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
     x=x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a} \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}\left(x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)+C_{2}\right)
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
     x=x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a} \\
     y=-\frac{1}{B_{2}}\left(A_{2}x_{B}+C_{2}\right)\pm \frac{1}{B_{2}}A_{2}B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$
$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
     x=x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a} \\
     y=y_{B}\pm A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$

Now check which one is the point we want to choose

$$\left(A_{1}x_{E}+B_{1}y_{E}+C_{1}\right)\left(A_{1}x_{C}+B_{1}y_{C}+C_{1}\right)>0\\
\left(A_{1}\left(x_{B}\mp B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)+B_{1}\left(y_{B}\pm A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)+C_{1}\right)\left(A_{1}\left(\left(x_{C}-x_{B}\right)+x_{B}\right)+B_{1}\left(\left(y_{C}-y_{B}\right)+y_{B}\right)+C_{1}\right)>0\\
\left(\mp A_{1}B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\pm B_{1}A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}+A_{1}x_{B}+B_{1}y_{B}+C_{1}\right)\left(A_{1}\left(-B_{2}+x_{B}\right)+B_{1}\left(A_{2}+y_{B}\right)+C_{1}\right)>0\\
\left(\mp A_{1}B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\pm B_{1}A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)\left(-A_{1}B_{2}+B_{1}A_{2}+A_{1}x_{B}+B_{1}x_{B}+C_{1}\right) > 0\\
 \frac{c}{a}\cdot\left(\mp A_{1}B_{2}\pm B_{1}A_{2}\right)\left(-A_{1}B_{2}+B_{1}A_{2}\right) > 0
$$

Now it should be clear which point should we choose

$$
\left \{
\begin{align}
     x_{E}=x_{B}-B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a} \\
     y_{E}=y_{B}+A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}
   \end{align}
\right. \\
$$

Let's calculate equation of line perpendicular to DE passing through point B

$$
y-y_{B}=-\frac{\left(x_{B}-B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)-x_{A}}{\left(y_{B}+A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)-y_{A}}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
y-y_{B}=-\frac{\left(\left(x_{B}-x_{A}\right)-B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)}{\left(\left(y_{B}-y_{A}\right)+A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}\right)}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
y-y_{B}=-\frac{-B_{1}-B_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}}{A_{1}+A_{2}\cdot\frac{c}{a}}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
y-y_{B}=\frac{B_{1}a+B_{2}c}{A_{1}a+A_{2}c}\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)\left(y-y_{B}\right)=\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)\left(x-x_{B}\right)\\
\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)\left(x-x_{B}\right)-\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)\left(y-y_{B}\right)=0\\
\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)x-\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)y-x_{B}\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)+y_{B}\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)=0
$$

It looks good, but when i performed the same calculation for vertex A
and tried to solve system of equations,
i could not simplify the solution to this system of equations (to show that solution indeed gives the coordinates of the center of inscribed circle).

I will not present all calculations for vertex A because they are almost the same as for vertex B

$$
|AC|=\sqrt{\left(x_{C}-x_{A}\right)^2+\left(y_{C}-y_{A}\right)^2}\\
|AC|=\sqrt{A_{3}^2+B_{3}^2}\\
|AC|=b
$$

System of equations from step 4. look as follows

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
    \left(x-x_{A}\right)^2+\left(y-y_{A}\right)^2=c^2 \\
     A_{3}x+B_{3}y+C_{3}=0
   \end{align}
\right.
$$

Solution to this equation is

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
     x=x_{A} \mp B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}\\
     y=y_{A} \pm A_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}
   \end{align}
\right.
$$

Now check which one is the point we want to choose

$$
\left(A_{1}x_{E}+B_{1}y_{E}+C_{1}\right)\left(A_{1}x_{C}+B_{1}y_{C}+C_{1}\right)>0\\
\frac{c}{b}\cdot\left(\mp A_{1}B_{3}\pm B_{1}A_{3}\right)\left(-A_{1}B_{3}+B_{1}A_{3}\right)>0
$$

Now it should be clear which point should we choose

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
     x_{E}=x_{A} - B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}\\
     y_{E}=y_{A} + A_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}
   \end{align}
\right.
$$

Now let's calculate the equation of perpendicular to DE and passing through point A where D is chosen to be equal to B

$$
y-y_{A}=-\frac{\left(x_{A}-B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}\right)-x_{B}}{\left(y_{A}+A_{3}\frac{c}{b}\right)-y_{B}}\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
y-y_{A}=-\frac{\left(\left(x_{A}-x_{B}\right)-B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}\right)}{\left(\left(y_{A}-y_{B}\right)+A_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}\right)}\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
y-y_{A}=-\frac{B_{1}-B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}}{-A_{1}+A_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}}\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
y-y_{A}=\frac{B_{1}-B_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}}{A_{1}-A_{3}\cdot\frac{c}{b}}\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
y-y_{A}=\frac{B_{1}b-B_{3}c}{A_{1}b-A_{3}c}\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)\left(y-y_{A}\right)=\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)\left(x-x_{A}\right)\\
\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)\left(x-x_{A}\right)-\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)\left(y-y_{A}\right)=0\\
\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)x-\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)y-x_{A}\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)+y_{A}\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)=0
$$

Now we have system of equations

$$
\left \{
  \begin{align}
   \left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)x-\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)y=x_{A}\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)-y_{A}\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right)\\
\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)x-\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)y=x_{B}\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)-y_{B}\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right)  
   \end{align}
\right.
$$

Now solution to this equation in matrix form is

$$
\begin{bmatrix}\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right) & -\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right) \\\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right) & -\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right) \end{bmatrix}^{-1}\cdot\begin{bmatrix}x_{A}\left(B_{1}b-B_{3}c\right)-y_{A}\left(A_{1}b-A_{3}c\right) \\x_{B}\left(B_{1}a+B_{2}c\right)-y_{B}\left(A_{1}a+A_{2}c\right) \end{bmatrix}
$$

I don't  know how can I simplify this solution 
(It should be the coordinates of center of inscribed circle)

Comment: Can anyone write me how to simplify it  Programs like Maple cannot